# Can I call js module in grunt configuration file gruntfile.coffee?

Tags: gruntjs

I'm using gruntjs to building my project. I want to utilize js module for multi-projects i.e. multi-gruntfile.

I see the API and search grunt plugins but not find what I want. It seems the only way is taking advantage of grunt.config and load-grunt-tasks plugin.

So I created js module file in the tasks folder and set configuration data in it like the following(by coffeescript):

```
module.exports = (grunt) ->
    _ret=null
    environmentObj=
     test: "test"
     verify: "beta"
     formal: "release"
    grunt.config.set('executeCustomTasks', (arg, arg1, arr) ->
        str = constructPromptStr();
        _ret = getVerInfo(arg1, arg)
        setArg()
    ...
    )
    setArg =  ->
       if _ret.verName is 'formal'
           _ret.verName = ''
       grunt.config.set('state',_ret.verName)
       grunt.config.set('date',_ret.verNum)
```

and call it like this:

```
grunt.task.registerTask('default', 'execute tasks by param by grunt cli', (arg, arg1) ->
        grunt.config.get('executeCustomTasks')(arg, arg1,getTasksArr(arg))

    )
```

Is what I do correct? Is it the best practice?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I understand now. grunt.task.loadTasks(path) can Load task-related files so I can create and reference the files in the path.
reference links:
http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task
https://github.com/cowboy/wesbos/commit/5a2980a7818957cbaeedcd7552af9ce54e05e3fb